# Two variable linear function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

It's been a while since I've been in any math classes. I have a linear function $(T-c)m = B$. I have many samples of $T$ and $B$, but no idea what $m$ and $c$ are. How do I solve this?

My first thought was to use limits to get $m$ and then just solve for $c$, but I don't know. Such a simple function, surely there is a simple way to solve it that I'm overlooking.

$c$ and $m$ are both constants by the way. As $T$ increases, so does $B$. $0 < m < 1$, $c > 0$.

Comment: the tags are a reflection that I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: ah perfect, you should put it as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).